# c3.js multi-line charts with missing data/different x values

Tags: c3.js

I have problem with c3.js with mutli-line chart and different x values in every line. 
For example:

```
 data1 = [
  {
    "date": 1470520800000,
    "admin": 10
  },
  {
    "date": 1470607200000,
    "admin": 10.06
  },
  {
    "date": 1470693600000,
    "admin": 10.03
  },
  {
    "date": 1470780000000,
    "admin": 10
  },
  {
    "date": 1470866400000,
    "admin": 10.05
  },
  {
    "date": 1470952800000,
    "admin": 10
  }
];

data2 = [
  {
    "date": 1470607200000,
    "user": 94.66
  },
  {
    "date": 1470693600000,
    "user": 316.58
  },
  {
    "date": 1470780000000,
    "user": 10
  },
  {
    "date": 1470866400000,
    "user": 1.5
  },
  {
    "date": 1470952800000,
    "user": 12
  }
];

    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            json: data1,
            keys: {
                x: 'date',
                value: ["admin"]
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: function (x) { return x.toLocaleDateString(); }
                }
            }
        },
        padding: {
            right: 50
        }
    });

    chart.load({
                json: data2,
                keys: {
                    x: "date",
                    value: ['user']
                }
            });
```

Data does not display well when i fucus on them with my mouse.
I post my code here https://jsfiddle.net/gahm5wgb/.

Answer (score 3):

I find solution for this problem. You just need to use Multiple XY Line Chart. Example: http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy_multiple.html

Comment: Best way for sure.. By default it will probably result in non-uniform tick values, so these can be adjusted with http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-values

Answer (score 0):

I have never used c3.js library, but add to data2 this object at the beginning:

```
  {
    "date": 1470520800000,
    "user": 0
  },
```

I think number of points aren't equal - data2 have 1 point less. It should resolve your problem :-)

Comment: That's the point. Data for chart are from database where some fields look like this, some have all fields and others not.
I will do this at the end: check if all data from db have all firlds and add when not but first I want to know that is other way to do this.